# Using random() in a header file

Tags: programming, c++

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

struct Foo{
  int randInt = random(0, 101);
};

#endif
```

I have a header file with a `struct` like above but when I compile I get this error:

`'random' was not declared in this scope`

How can I use random() in a header file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `#include <Arduino.h>` like this

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <Arduino.h>

struct Foo{
  int randInt = random(0, 101);
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

The struct is a declaration of a type. You cannot mix it with the initialization. This is how it could be:

In foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

struct Foo{
  int randInt;
};

extern struct Foo foo;
struct Foo *initFoo(struct Foo *foo_ptr);
#endif
```

In foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h"

struct Foo foo;
struct Foo *initFoo(struct Foo *foo_ptr) {
  if (!foo_ptr)
    return NULL;
  foo_ptr->randInt = random(0, 101);
  return foo_ptr;
}
```

random() is a function and therefore its return value cannot be used as static initializer.
Unless -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 are enabled.

Comment: It's valid C++ code I don't see why it would be different for an Arduino. The code works fine after I `#include <Arduino.h>`.

Comment: What is the outcome?  Did you try to compile _exactly_ the code you put in your question?

Comment: I answered my question and it works as is. The only problem was that `random()` was defined in my header file so I had to include the Arduino library. Someone commented for me to do but it's gone now, I guess they deleted it.

Comment: With gcc, it works only with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11.
Probably the Arduino ide turns them on by default.

Comment: Maybe so, I didn't actually want to use `random()` as an initializer (I'm using it in another function within the header) it was just easier to use it in the initializer here (less code to display). It works for me though granted I am using stino with sublime text 3.

Comment: Arduino does in fact have -std=gnu++11 by default